# Oracle: Update CLOB form another table that is bigger than 4000 characters

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, clob

How can i do that?

```
UPDATE 
    My_Table SET my_clob = (
        SELECT 
            other_clob
        FROM 
            other_table
        WHERE 
            my_table.id = other_table.id
    );
```

Error:

> ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion

EDIT:

Oh boy, sry guys. I turns out the column actually was a varchar(4000) in the test system i was testing doing this (in prod its a clob as it should be). Kind of makes you wonder if i was the first one to actually use the test system...

Comment: Have you tried to use DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is allegedly [fixed in oracle 10.2](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_22835_buffer_too_small.htm). It certainly works in [oracle 11g R2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c3d5f/1)

If you can't upgrade, try using some PL/SQL:

```
begin
  for rec in (select id, other_clob from other_table) loop
    update my_table set my_clob = rec.other_clob where id = rec.id;
  end loop;
end;
/
```